# Using VBA Function in Access Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I want to write an SQL query using MS access, which calculates a serial number using a VBA Function.

I have a big "samplebasicinformation" table which has lots of foreign keys and want to use the text fields in the foreign tables to create a text-based serial number.

I want the first field of the query to abbreviate a few text fields from other tables, then concatenate them and create this serial number.

In order to abbreviate the text fields I have the following function:

```
Function GetFirstLetters(rng As String)
Dim arr
Dim I As Long
arr = VBA.Split(rng, " ")
If IsArray(arr) Then
    For I = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        GetFirstLetters = GetFirstLetters & Left(arr(I), 1)
    Next I
Else
    GetFirstLetters = Left(arr, 1)
End If
End Function
```

I've tried the below SQL to achieve this but failed due to syntax error.

```
SELECT 
(getfirstletters(select sl.locationname from samplebasicinformation as sbi join samplelocation as sl 
on sbi.samplelocationid = sl.samplelocationid)), 
samplebasicinformationid 
from samplebasicinformation as sbi1
```

Would anyone be able to offer some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to feed a single column to your function.

Your query is rather confusing, I think it is as simple as this:

```sql
SELECT 
  getfirstletters(sl.locationname),
  sbi.samplebasicinformationid 
FROM samplebasicinformation as sbi 
  INNER JOIN samplelocation as sl 
  on sbi.samplelocationid = sl.samplelocationid
```

Note that you need `INNER JOIN` in Access Sql.

Comment: Obligatory link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3PAKUWm9Oc

Comment: Worked first time and thank you for reminding me I haven't watched gladiator recently enough. Thank you Andre!